How do I remove the wires from this connector?
Is it possible to remove the wires and reuse this connector? How are they held in place? Or do I need to get a whole new connector?

That looks similar to the connectors on ATX power supplies. If so, there are tabs on both sides of the connector that need to be simultaneously depressed. You may need a removal tool, especially if you intend to reuse the pins. (But note also removal will degrade the pins and make them less likely to be properly retained when reinserted.) If possible, you're better off cutting the pins off, or even replacing the wire in entirety.


The contacts are crimped to the wires. They can be released from the connector body by sliding a thin tool in to depress the tabs which are conveniently visible in the picture, and pulling on the wire attached to each. There is a formal tool available for the purpose, but improvised tools will work if you understand the principle. There may only be one tab per contact, or there may be two, with the other on the opposite side from the ones we can see.
Re-using the connector body is typically feasible, while the contacts normally have to be replaced with new ones. Since there does not appear to be any damage to the wires right at the connector, a simpler approach to re-using the connector would be to cut the old wires leaving enough wire to "butt-splice" each to the new wires with an insulated butt-splice of the appropriate size for each of the wires.

Image source, no endorsement implied

Releasing those tabs is like lock picking.   One of these days might break down and buy a wire terminal removal kit.

If you like saving money and DIY, take connectors of the sizes you need tools for to the hobby store and buy some tiny tubing of the right diameter & wall thickness for a lot less than most places sell the tools for.  The tool is basically that in a handle, and a handle is easy. You can look at images and grind shapes to match the commercial tools, but the plain tube will normally work fine.

I've reused many contacts in my days., re crimp or solder.

Cutting the wire far from the connector and soldering & heatshrink tubing the cable has always been much easier for me. It is possible to uncrimp/recrimp, but also very easy to mangle the socket metal - they are latched to go in and stick in only one direction (like a harpoon). Beyond my skill level - they always come out mangled and never work quite the same.
The reason to do so is that identifying the type of connector is so hard! But a new connector is only $1 from mouser/digikey. Try google reverse image search?

@Ecnerwal A jeweler's screwdriver or two works very nearly as well as the tube-type too in my experience, and isn't particular as to the specific size of the connector.  The key is that they're hardened steel so they can be long and thin without being bendy like a paperclip is.

A pin removal kit can be had from Amazon for $10.  Mine has been well worth it—used it quite a few times particularly for automotive electricals when I didn't want to deal with soldering and/or crimping.
